# situation of values in cpu befor switching

Tags: assembly

I know that when a sample assembly program is running and the CPU is executing the instructions one by one, actually because of being the timesharing OS (for example, Windows 7 or XP) the CPU is switching between all the programs and executing the codes (executing one code from this program and then one code from another program in memory).

Where does the CPU keep the value of the registers from last executed instruction when it is not yet done with that process:

```
program A:
( 
  mov al,23h
  mov bl,32h
  .........
  .........
)
program B:
(
  mov al,10h
  mov bl,12h
)
```

Now, if we consider these two programs in memory, when the CPU executes the first instruction of the first program (program A:) and in the next step the CPU switches, and begins executing the first instruction of the next program (program B:) where does the CPU save the value in the registers before switching to the program B:?

Comment: It is called 'Context Switching'. This page has detailed explanation. http://wiki.osdev.org/Context_Switching

Comment: 'timesharing OS' is rather a loose way of desribing a preemptive multitasker:)

Comment: @9dan - site fail.  Mentions 'time slice' in second sentence.  It's only a short step from there to 'quantum' and devs. believing that 'timesharing' is normal and not a sign of an overloaded box.